# Bit error probability for BFSK

Tags: communication, digital-communications, fsk

This is an assignment question.

What is the probability of bit error of a BFSK modulation scheme with transmitted energy per bit E<sub>b</sub> , in a additive white Gaussian noise channel having one-sided power spectral density N ? Please give the answer in temrs of erfc function.

**My solution** : I know the formula for probability of bit error in terms of Q-function:

\$P_e = Q\left[\sqrt{\frac{E_b}{N}}\right]\$

Q-function is related to complementary error function erfc as :

Q(z) = 0.5 * erfc(z/square-root(2) )

So the final answer in terms of erfc should be : 0.5 * erfc( square-root(E<sub>b</sub>/**2**N) )

**Given answer** : 0.5 * erfc( square-root(E<sub>b</sub>/N) )

There is a difference of 2 in my answer and the given answer. Please tell me where am I going wrong.

PS :  square-root has its usual meaning. Square-root(2) = 1.414. I don't know how to use math symbols here yet.

Comment: Can someone kindly tell me how to use math symbols like square root, etc.  in stack exchange ? Do I need to install any software ? I use Google Chrome as my browser.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/most-common-mathjax-uses-in-electrical-engineering

Comment: I updated the first equation for you.  Between that and the guides posted, you should be able to get the mathJax going for the rest of them.